# Storing and Accessing graph attributes in pythons networkx

Tags: python, networkx

How do I read, update, and write a value to a graph in Pythons Networkx?

I know I can do it at creation by using

```
graph = nx.Graph(name="Simulation_General_Voter_Model")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add values to a graph during creation by using:

```
graph = nx.Graph(name="A lovely graph", some_other_value=17)
```

Alternatively, you can add values later on using:

```
graph.later_value = "this was added later"
```

You can access these values intuitively using:

```
print(graph.name, graph.some_other_value, graph.later_value)
```

I couldn't find this information in the documentation. :/